# The same msbulid.exe shows different version on different machines

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix

I am trying to replicate my development environment into my build server in order to debug an error that occurs only in the build server, The same solution is compiled with msbuild that is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe in both machines.

In the development machine, the solution is getting compiled successfully while in the build server it fails.

Reading the outputs from msbuild I noticed that in both machines the build is done with different versions of Microsoft build engine

dev machine: 14.0.25420.1

build server:14.0.23107.0

In order to rule out that this error relates to the version
I tried to pass the msbuild from the dev machine to the build server and ran it there which output the build server version.

How can the same msbuild yield different version on a different machine?

How can I update the build engine?

Answer (score 0):

> How can the same msbuild yield different version on a different machine?

According to the official blog [MSBuild is now part of Visual Studio!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/):

> Starting with Visual Studio 2013, the 2013 version of MSBuild will
>   ship as a part of Visual Studio instead of the .NET Framework.

So at this moment, MSBuild.exe have the same version of Visual Studio 2015, you can check the version of Visual Studio 2015:

[image]

So update the version of Visual Studio on the build server to have the same version MSBuild.exe.

**Update for comment:**

> Is it possible to update msbuild without installing visual studio?

The answer is yes, you can download the [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=48159&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True&a03ffa40-ca8b-4f73-0358-c191d75a7468=True), install it to update msbuild.exe without installing Visual Studio.

Please refer to the document [MSBuild is now part of Visual Studio!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/) for details:

> The New Microsoft® Build Tools Package
>
> MSBuild is now a component of Visual Studio and will ship with all
>   SKUs of Visual Studio, including Team Build so if you use Visual
>   Studio all of your build needs should be covered. We understand that
>   there are a great number of reasons that you may want to use MSBuild
>   and other build tools without needing to install Visual Studio so we
>   are making the tools available as a new standalone package called
>   Microsoft® Build Tools. The package includes MSBuild and the VB/C#
>   compilers. The new package can be acquired here on the MSDN Download
>   Center.
>
> This standalone package is great for build servers requiring fine
>   grain control of their build process. With this new approach to
>   evolving MSBuild, you have more control over build behavior and are
>   not impacted by .NET Framework versions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to update msbuild without installing visual studio?

Comment: In addition, I want to be able to control the version of msbuild(build with different msbuild versions) from one server, how can it be done if msbuild is depended on Visual Studio?

Comment: @CountOren, the answer is yes, you can refer to the updated answer for details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I did try to use the build tools and installed with it .net core 1.0 (which from my understanding should update the msbuild) and running "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /version outputs version 14.0.23107.0 note that as well bringing the msbuild from the dev machine(which on the dev machine yields:14.0.25420.1)  and run it, outputs 14.0.23107.0 on the build server, which made me think maybe msbuild is refering to another process (like COM object) in the machine in order to decide what version is running.

Comment: AFAIK, the build tool 2015 should not compatible with .net core 1.0, it compatible with .net core 1.0 preview. And .net core 1.0 ship with Visual Studio 2017. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.0

Comment: After installing VS2015 msbuild version (even the one brought from the dev machine) was updated to 14.0.25420.1 and uninstalling VS2015 put them back to the old version.Microsoft Build Tools 2015 did not update the msbuilds versions.

Comment: @CountOren, What I know is that the VS2015 has certain update like this document:https://omwtm.blog/2014/12/03/visual-studio-2013-version-numbers-and-updates/, a simple way for us to make sure that whether it updated the MSbuild version, we could view all packages' release date. Actually you could install the update3 version for build tool 2015 in your side:https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615458